# Add onTap to CheckboxListTile to call AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a Flutter mobile application for taking attendance.

I am using CheckboxListTile for displaying enrollment list. I would like to call Alert Dialog when I click or tap a list item. However, I find that CheckboxListTile does not have onTap property.

So is there any way to add onTap to CheckboxListTile? Thanks!

A part of my code for creating CheckboxListTile:

```
  Widget staffList(AsyncSnapshot<EnrollmentListModel> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data.staffList.length > 0) {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.staffList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(
                '${snapshot.data.staffList[index].listName}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              value: snapshot.data.staffList[index].attendanceStatus == 'Y',
              onChanged: (bool value) {},
              activeColor: Colors.green,
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
    else {
      return Center(child: Text("No enrollment for this course."));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `onTap` is not working is because the `checkboxListTile` itself is clickable and if we try to apply `onTap` on it again, it'll conflict the original click event. So instead of wrapping your `checkboxListTile` in `GestureDetector`, you can directly pass the call to open `alertDialog` in your `onChanged` method after you set the value upon clicking on it.  Sample working code below:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('CheckboxListTile demo')),
      body: ListView(
        children: values.keys.map((String key) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(key),
              value: values[key],
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  values[key] = value;
                });
                _showDialog();
              },
            );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
      // return object of type Dialog
      return AlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
        content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text("Close"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
```

The output is, if you tap on `foo` checkbox, it'll check the box and will open alertDialog.  Hope this answers your question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `CheckboxListTile` inside a `GestureDetector`, which has a `onTap` property along with many others which you might find useful.

More documentation about the `GestureDetector` class can be found [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

Example -

```
  Widget staffList(AsyncSnapshot<EnrollmentListModel> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data.staffList.length > 0) {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.staffList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                //Add code for showing AlertDialog here
              },
              child: CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(
                  '${snapshot.data.staffList[index].listName}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                value: snapshot.data.staffList[index].attendanceStatus == 'Y',
                onChanged: (bool value) {},
                activeColor: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
    else {
      return Center(child: Text("No enrollment for this course."));
    }
  }
```

**Alternative -**
You can also use the `InkWell` widget if you only need the `onTap` callback. Just replace the `GestureDetector` in above code with `InkWell`.

Documentation about `InkWell` can be found [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html).

Comment: Thanks!. I have tried out both widgets and they are easy to use. However, onTap is not working for "CheckboxListTile", the Alert Dialog did not pop up when I tap on the list item. I tried "onDoubleTap" to test showing Alert Dialog, it works normally...

Comment: The `onTap` not working might be since `CheckboxListTile` also has a handler for taps which is overriding the `GestureDetector` tap. Can you try checking the `behaviour` property of the `GestureDetector`? I think you might need to set it to `HitTestBehavior.translucent` to so that both the `GestureDetector` and `CheckBoxListTile` are able to recognize the tap.

Comment: Yes, I have the same finding as yours, CheckboxListTile's onTap will call Checkbox's onChanged.

Comment: I tried  `behaviour: HitTestBehavior.translucent` and other values but the results are negative. I may change to use `ListTile` with `trailing: Checkbox` instead of `CheckboxListTile` if the issue cannot be solved. Thanks anyway. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
body: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
                onTap: () {//Write your AlertDialog code here},
              );
            },
            itemCount: 10));
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is not essentially different from the other answer and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers, either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether, this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful not scattered/duplicated. Cheers!